# NETLink System.AccessViolationException when compiling #C with .NET 4.0 or higher

Tags: .netlink

I have a program, which used NETlink to call *Mathematica* functions from C#. When we compile this program with .NET 4.0 or higher we get 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Wolfram.NETLink.dll"

And trace here:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     Source=Wolfram.NETLink
>     StackTrace:
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.Win64MathLinkAPIProvider.MLNextPacket(IntPtr link)
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.Win64MathLinkAPIProvider.extMLNextPacket(IntPtr link)
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.NativeLink.NextPacket()
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.WrappedKernelLink.NextPacket()
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.KernelLinkImpl.WaitForAnswer()
>          at Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.Compute()

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want help with this please [edit] your question and provide a *bare bones/cut down* example of the Mathematica code and the C# calling code. A [mcve] is required to reproduce the problem to apply troubleshooting and diagnose the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

AccessViolationException  is explicit  : somehow your program is accessing memory that it doesn't have right to access (didn't allocate for ex).

Since it' s in the another library, you're probably passing bad arguments to the .NETLink . or (less likely) the library contains a bug ...